# Procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created a procedure (`sp_ET1_ClassificacaoPPIInferior`) to sort by score (`Numr_TotalEt1`) a particular category (`TipoPrograma = 1`) of candidates already in the table (`CandidatosVestAtual`):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CandidatosVestAtual](
[NUMG_Candidato] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[CODG_Curso] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
[TipoPrograma] [int] NOT NULL,
[Numr_TotalEt1] [int] NULL,
[Numr_Classificacao_PPIInf_Et1] [int] NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CandidatosVestAtual_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NUMG_Candidato] ASC)
)
```

Follows the codes of procedure used:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ET1_ClassificacaoPPIInferior] @CODG_Curso varchar(4)
AS

DECLARE @Cnt INT
DECLARE @NUMG_Candidato INT

    DECLARE Candidatos_C CURSOR FOR


    SELECT NUMG_Candidato
    FROM CandidatosVestAtual
    WHERE TipoPrograma in (1) AND 
    Codg_Curso =@CODG_Curso
    ORDER BY Numr_TotalEt1 DESC



    set @Cnt = 1
     OPEN Candidatos_C
     FETCH NEXT FROM Candidatos_C INTO @NUMG_Candidato
      WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
      BEGIN 


        UPDATE CandidatosVestAtual SET Numr_Classificacao_PPIInf_Et1=@Cnt
        FROM CandidatosVestAtual
        WHERE NUMG_Candidato=@NUMG_Candidato

        SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
        FETCH NEXT FROM Candidatos_C INTO @NumG_Candidato
      END

     CLOSE Candidatos_C
     DEALLOCATE Candidatos_C
```

However this procedure does nothing as it stands. It's done some thing only when I change the original query the procedure:

```
SELECT NUMG_Candidato 
FROM CandidatosVestAtual 
WHERE TipoPrograma in (1) 
  AND Codg_Curso = @ CODG_Curso 
ORDER BY DESC Numr_TotalEt1
```

By

```
SELECT NUMG_Candidato 
FROM CandidatosVestAtual 
WHERE Codg_Curso = @CODG_Curso 
ORDER BY DESC Numr_TotalEt1
```

How can I make the procedure work with the original query?

Comment: Are you sure that there are records in that table that match the original query?  If you remove one of the criteria, and then it works, that should tell you that the issue is with the data.

Comment: Also, you should consider replacing this cursor with a set-based operation... this would be fairly easily to re-implement using a `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: do you get results when you run `SELECT NUMG_Candidato
    FROM CandidatosVestAtual
    WHERE TipoPrograma in (1)`
?

Comment: I'm sure there is data in the table that correspond to the original query, for example, ran a query: SELECT NUMG_Candidato
FROM CandidatosVestAtual
WHERE TipoPrograma in (1) AND
Codg_Curso = 'A105'
ORDER BY DESC Numr_TotalEt1

and records were returned.

Answer (score 0):

problem is varchar and varchar(6), please check Your Proc peremeter is  @CODG_Curso varchar(6) and table schema field def is [CODG_Curso] varchar NOT NULL..

Comment: I'm sure there is data in the table that correspond to the original query, for example, just ran the query: SELECT NUMG_Candidato
FROM CandidatosVestAtual
WHERE TipoPrograma in (1) AND
Codg_Curso = 'A105'
ORDER BY DESC Numr_TotalEt1

and records were returned. However when I run the procedure nothing is done: run dbo.sp_ET1_ClassificacaoPPIInferior 'A105';

Comment: Modified proc with peremeter @CODG_Curso varchar(4) then try it.

use like instade of = in where clase..

Comment: Modified proc with peremeter @CODG_Curso varchar(4) but did not work

Comment: did you try  TipoPrograma = 1 instade  TipoPrograma in (1).

Comment: can you share how your query look like!

Answer (score 0):

I created some fake data using

```
declare @i int = 1
while @i <= 100
Begin
insert into [CandidatosVestAtual]
(NUMG_Candidato,
CODG_Curso,
TipoPrograma,
Numr_TotalEt1,
Numr_Classificacao_PPIInf_Et1)
select @I, 'a', 1, 1

end
```

When I run the procedure

```
[dbo].[sp_ET1_ClassificacaoPPIInferior] 'a'
```

The data in Numr_Classificacao_PPIInf_Et1 is cleanly incremented. Remove the update from your trigger and replace with a select of

```
select @Cnt, @NUMG_Candidato
```

If this increments data; are you trapped in a transactional rollback? If it doesnt can you comment out / trim out till it works and say where it starts to work again?